ECS Task Performance monitoring : Wrong Memory Utilization Statistics
I have an ecs service running two tasks with 8 gb of memory each. The task is running a spring boot application, I have set the JVM heap size of 7.5gb max and min.
Now in my logs I can see from Garbage Collection Statistics that JVM has utlized 99.9% is 7.4xx gb of memory and is throwing OutOfMemory exception. But in container insights -> performance monitoring  -> memory utilization is being shown as only 6% . What could  be the reason for this?
